# Позиционирование изображения в div

Tags: html, css

есть

```
div
{
height:200px;
width:200px;
}
```

как в него поместить картинку по центру (по вертикали и по горизонтали), если не известен ее размер

Comment: изображение не должно быть фоновым

Comment: сам отвечу)
<pre>
            #one
            {
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                background: #8498C1;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 600px;
                position: relative;
            }
            
            img{
                
                width:300px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                top:0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin: auto;
            }
<\pre>

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/3s3eG/

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
div img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://allworldsms.com/images/red_sml/jpg/ph_c3_t2/p20.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/t1.0-1/p48x48/198439_142428352491010_4885397_t.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://pynet.su/_sf/24/2437.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
background: url(../images/picture.png) center;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/psPfL/

```css
#wr {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#im {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='wr'>
    <div id='im'></div>
</div>
```